# How do I install Codeblocks 17.12?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, deb, code-blocks

I just downloaded the compressed files from Codeblocks website but there are so many `.deb` files.

[image]

So which one should I install? Do I have to remove currently installed Codeblocks 16.01 before performing installation? If anyone describes the process in a bit detail, it'll be really helpful. I am a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vABwWSZLMMY

*** Here are the steps in the videos ***

Step 1:

First install pre-processor, compiler, and wrapper by running following command

```sh
sudo apt-get install gpp gcc g++
```

Step 2:

Download Code::Blocks binary  "codeblocks_17.12-1_amd64_stable.tar.xz" from official CodeBlocks website.

Step 3:

Extract downloaded archive with

```sh
tar -xf codeblocks_17.12-1_amd64_stable.tar.xz
```

Then install extracted deb-packages with

```sh
sudo dpkg -i *17.12*.deb
```

And finally, install missed dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeblocks_17.12_1 works nice on a clean install of
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and spent a day coding and not seen
any of the IDE`s usual GUI problems previously
experienced when using Codeblocks v16.01 on Ubuntu 17.10+ ;)

Extra Dependencies Required (+current codeblocks-contrib);-

```sh
sudo apt-get install libwxbase3.0 cccc cppcheck cscope hunspell valgrind python3-pygments wx3.0
```

Then Codeblocks_17.12_1 and plugins install without problems.

Thanks Codeblocks coders and contributors, I have
been using this IDE for many years.

Comment: Preparing to unpack codeblocks_17.12-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking codeblocks (17.12-1) over (16.01+dfsg-2.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive codeblocks_17.12-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/codeblocks/plugins/libabbreviations.so', which is also in package codeblocks-contrib 16.01+dfsg-2.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 codeblocks_17.12-1_amd64.deb                                                                                   I am getting this error message

Comment: Maybe remove the old codeblocks contrib version:- sudo apt remove codeblocks-contrib  && sudo apt autoremove